# UIWebView load data crashes on iOS 9 if the baseURL is NSURL() as URL (swift version >= 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have the following:

```
self.webView?.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)
```

works well on iOS 10 and above but crashes on iOS 9.

crash logs:
Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional' to 'NSURL'.

Comment: You need to provide details about the crash. Please [edit] your question with all relevant details.

Comment: And why are you even using `NSURL`? Just use `URL`.

Comment: I already have the pdf data ready to load on the web view and I don't have/need a baseURL in this case.